# Render multiple instances of bind-component / Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, components, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have the following component

```
<script>
    let item = null
    export let text = "loading"

    onMount(() => {
        parent = item
        text = parent.querySelector("p")

        parent.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
            text.style.fontSize = "4rem"
        })
    })
</script>

<div bind:this={item}>
    <p>{text}</p>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to render it dynamicly while looping over some data.

But the problem is, that all instances of the component are packed into one element.
So there aren't e.g 5 components with text in it. But there's only one component with 5 p-tags in it. I also tried to use `querySelector` instead of `bind:this`. But this resulted in a way more worse haha.

So is there any way to use bind:this for multiple instances of the component? That in the onMount Function it always grabs the right one?

Comment: You can do this with simply css ? Or if you need more complexity maybe use actions instead ?

Comment: Everything about this is wrong. Use [`{#each}`](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each) to loop over lists and create elements/components in HTML, use CSS (`:hover`) for styling. There is no need for *any* JS. By using code to manipulate the DOM you are throwing all advantages of Svelte out the window.